# How can I draw several lines in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would also have a contour and vector field on the plot, and I would like to draw several lines on it. But when I used ax.plot for several times, only one line is shown.

like this

```
ax.plot([-1,-1], [1,1],linewidth=3,c='y')
```

Comment: Can you give us more details? What's the code of your "several times of ax.plot"? Are you using Matplotlib interactively or in a script? What platform are you using? What version are you using? If you are using it correctly, Matplotlib does support multiple ax.plot. See https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface for the official example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x1 = [10,20,30]
y1 = [20,40,10]
#plot the first line
ax.plot(x1, y1)

x2 = [10,20,30]
y2 = [40,10,30]
#plot the second line
ax.plot(x2, y2)

plt.show()
```

This piece of code should be able to produce multiple lines in the same axes